# Transpose rows 1 and 0 's into different rows in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to load a file and transpose the row into different rows.

Days Column have 11010011 and need to transpose into vertical format.

Below is the sample input

[image]

I'm trying to get the expected output like below

[image]

Can you please help me on this in Snowflake? Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace '1' with '1,' and '0' with '0,'. Trim the trailing comma. You can then use split to table to turn that into rows:

```
with SOURCE_DATA as
(
select   COLUMN1::int as FACTORY
        ,COLUMN2::int as YEAR
        ,COLUMN3::string as DAYS
from (values 
(01,2021,'01010100100101010001'),
(99,2021,'00100111010101011010')
     )
)
select   FACTORY, YEAR, SEQ as SOURCE_ROW, INDEX as POSITION_IN_STRING, VALUE as WORKING_DAY
from SOURCE_DATA, table(split_to_table(trim(replace(replace(DAYS,'1','1,'),'0','0,'),','),',')) D
;
```

Abbreviated output:

| FACTORY | YEAR | SOURCE_ROW | POSITION_IN_STRING | WORKING_DAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021 | 1 | 5 | 0 |

The split() table function gives you some metadata columns with information on the split. You can change the sample to select * to see them and maybe they're useful in some way for your requirements.